# Can you use the HTML5 details tag to open up a description box to the right instead of underneath the <li>?

Tags: css, html, angular, typescript

I was looking for a way to use the details tag as an expandable list, however I would like for it to open up to the right, say a div, as a separate "window". Is this at all possible doing it this way? Or is there a better way to do this in angular2?

Appreciate all suggestions!

The code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos | items: items">
      <details>
        <summary>
          {{todo.text}}
        </summary>
        <p>
          Hey, this is a paragraph
        </p>
      </details>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Well... Basically. I have a to do list, the items list vertically: 1, 2, 3 etc. When you click on that item I'd like it to open another "box" next to it, say, with a description box. Example: Go shopping -> buy milk, flower, egg, should be inside of the description box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: absolute` or `float: right`

example with `position`...

```css
p {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos | items: items">
    <details>
      <summary>
        {{todo.text}}
      </summary>
      <p>
        Hey, this is a paragraph   Hey, this is a paragraph Hey, this is a paragraph Hey, this is a paragraph Hey, this is a paragraph
      </p>
    </details>
  </li>
</ul>
```